# Convert a text file with Embedded HP Printer Codes to PostScript

Tags: printing, postscript

I have an application that prints by generating text files with embedded printer codes, then basically just copies the file to the printer to print.  I need to take that print file and convert it to an image - just as if it was printed then scanned.

My first thought was to setup a printer with a postscript printer driver attached to a file port, and then run the result through ghostscript to create a tiff, but it isn't working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The printer codes are probably PCL. Maybe [pcl-parser](https://pcl-parser.dev.java.net/) could serve as a start for your own tool to do this? There also seems to be a commercial product called [PCLXForm](http://www.pclxform.com/).

Edit: Also investigate [GhostPCL](http://www.artifex.com/downloads/).

Comment: The PCLXForm looks like exactly what I need, and isn't too expensive. Thanks - I searched google for days before I asked here.  Next time I'll just ask here first :-)